# The order of my javascript include tags matters and I don't understand why

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, uploadify

I am using paperclip with uploadify and I was able to get it working fine. I am also using some AJAX so that a couple of submit buttons do not trigger a reload of the whole page. It was working fine before and it has stopped working now (the log shows that no js.erb is called).

This is what I have in my app:

```
[remi@iMac]$ l public/javascripts/
total 728
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff     148 May 17 08:01 application.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff   34787 May 17 08:01 controls.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff   31056 May 17 08:01 dragdrop.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff   38467 May 17 08:01 effects.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff   72328 May 22 10:50 jquery-1.4.2.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff  162353 May 17 08:01 prototype.js
-rw-r--r--@ 1 remi  staff    5850 May 17 08:01 rails.js
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 remi  staff   10220 May 17 08:01 swfobject.js
drwxr-xr-x  5 remi  staff     170 May 22 10:38 uploadify
```

And I noticed that the order of the javascript include tags makes a difference. When I include jquery first, uploadify does not work but ajax works fine.

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.js" %>   
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

When I change it, then uploadify works but clicking on my ajax buttons reloads the page:

```
   <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.4.2.js" %>
```

I am still new to this, can you point me to an explanation of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess jQuery and Prototype are fighting for the `$`.

You should setup `jquery-rails` in your app so that Rails will rely on the framework you're using elsewhere.

See reference [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. The following script solved my issue (found here: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-prototype-to-jquery/)

`<script>
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript files are loaded in "order of appearance". You need to include them the way you want them to work with the other JavaScript files.

For instance:

```
<script>
    // I need some stuff written in script1.js
</script>
<script src="script1.js"></script>
```

Won't work, because you need script1.js to be loaded before your stuff.

That's why JavaScript libraries (like jQuery or Prototype) must be loaded first (top of you  inclusions). That's why your AJAX stuff doesn't work when it's loaded before jQuery.

Comment: sorry for the grammar, I'm French :D

Comment: Ok I see. In that case, should I get rid of everything that is not jQuery and rewrite my AJAX mechanisms?